# Jlib 401 unauthorized error when pushing image in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, pom.xml, dockerhub

I am going to dockerize my microservice project to dockerhub by jlib .But when i run it , i just encounter the 401 error for registry to dockerhub.Here is my code:

pom:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <from>
            <image>eclipse-temurin:17.0.4.1_1-jre</image>
          </from>
          <to>
            <image>registry.hub.docker.com/freelance_platform/${artifactId}</image>
          </to>

        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

setting.xml in .m2

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository/>
    <servers>
    <server>
    <id>registry.hub.docker.com</id>
    <username>*****</username>
    <password>****</password>
</server>
    </servers>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <userPluginRegistry/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <mirrors/>
    <proxies/>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.2.1:build (default) on project userjob: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry.hub.docker.com/freelance_platform/userjob' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for registry.hub.docker.com/freelance_platform/userjob: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```